# In the sentence "What are the benefits of earning money?" what part of speech is the word "earning"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, parts-of-speech, gerunds

In the sentence:

> What are the benefits of earning money?

What part of speech is the word "earning"? And what function does it serve to the word "money" after that?

Answer (score 3):

As another answer notes, "earning" is a gerund. If you look up its headword form ("earn") in a dictionary, the part of speech is verb. In your sentence, it functions as the object of the preposition "of", so some people would say that it acts as a noun, and some people might even call it a noun.

"Earning" is the parent of "money", which functions as its direct object.

By the way, this is only one interpretation. Some people might refer to "gerund-participles", "prepositional complements", etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Earning" here is a gerund, a verb acting as a noun; together with "money" it is a prepositional complement.

[Purdue Owl](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/index.html)

[Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/gerund/)

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund)

Comment: What part of the speech is the word: "benefit"?

Comment: No, @garnerstan, "earning" is a verb. Plain and simple. Nouns don't have objects, but verbs do!